# Compiling ndk library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, vnc

I need to compile c++ [library](https://github.com/deathlord87/droid-VNC-server) with aosp for x86 architecture

i'm following next steps:
"1 Part"

> 1. `$ cd <aosp_folder>`
> 2. `$ . build/envsetup.sh`
> 3. `$ lunch`
> 4. `$ ln -s <droid-vnc-folder>/nativeMethods/ external/`

"2 Part"

> 1. `$ cd external/nativeMethods`
> 2. `$ mm .`
> 3. `$ cd <droid-vnc-folder>`
> 4. `$ ./updateExecsAndLibs.sh`

First part is fine, but second gives me an error.
The problem appears on the mm . step.

============================================ 
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL 
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.0.1  
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86 
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng 
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release 
TARGET_BUILD_APPS= 
TARGET_ARCH=x86 
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86 
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT= 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH= 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT= 
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT= 
HOST_ARCH=x86_64 
HOST_OS=linux 
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.2.0-27-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty 
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release 
BUILD_ID=LRX22C

## OUT_DIR=out

> make: Entering directory `/home/user/aosp'
>   make: *** No rule to make target`out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbinder_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvnc_flinger_sdk21_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
>   make: Leaving directory`/home/user/aosp'

make failed to build some targets (11 seconds)

Environment: ubuntu 14.04, java7 same as [required](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) .
Aosp Repo synced.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `mm` bash function, the module may not have the required dependencies of your target. Look in the Android.mk file from the project you are trying to build and find the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable. Then try `make <target>` replacing `<target>` with the value from `LOCAL_MODULE`. This should attempt to build the required dependencies. Once the dependencies are built once then you can use `mm`.

Alternatively, you can build the the module with `mma`, that incorporates the required dependencies for that module.